# Code is not working when using templateUrl instead of using template in angular2

Tags: angular, templates, typescript, ionic-framework

Below code is not working while using "**templateUrl**" directive but while using "**template**" this code is working

What is the problem about this situation?
I want to use templateUrl directive instead of template in order to discriminate the designers and  programmers !!!

templateUrl and template are the same  ....

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-navbar>
  <button ion-button menuToggle>
   <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
 <ion-title>CONTACTS</ion-title>
 <ion-buttons end>
   <button ion-button icon-only (click)="openAddContactPage()">
     <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
   </button>
  </ion-buttons>
 </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
<ion-searchbar  (ionInput)="getContacts(0, 10, 'contacts','search',$event, '')"></ion-searchbar>

<ion-list>

<ion-item *ngFor="let c of contacts">

  <ion-avatar item-left>
    <img *ngIf="c.imageId != null" src="{{BACKEND_PATH}}/api/images/{{c.imageId}}">
    <img *ngIf="c.imageId.length == 0" src="../../assets/imgs/contact.png">
  </ion-avatar>
  <h2 bold>{{c.firstName}} {{c.lastName}}</h2>
  <p><span *ngIf="c.department != null">{{c.department}}: </span>{{c.job}}  </p>
  <p>{{c.companyName}}</p>
  <p>{{c.imageId}} .. {{c.imageId.length}}</p>
  <ion-note item-right>
    <ion-icon ios="ios-arrow-dropright" md="md-arrow-dropright"></ion-icon>
  </ion-note>
 </ion-item>

 </ion-list>
```

Comment: The error message you get when trying this is what? Have you tried wrapping it all in a `div` or `template` tag when you moved it to it's own file?

Comment: show us the component, particularly how you define the `templateUrl`